# Broken Fence Post Fix?

Tags: fence

I have a broken 4x4" fence post at bottom.
Post is in concrete 
Wondering the best fix without digging up concrete and doing it all over.
Thanks!

Comment: You might get better answers to this question on the DIY stackexchange site (https://diy.stackexchange.com/) instead of the woodworking site.

Comment: A pic is really vital to help with getting on-point Answers here, if you can't take one of your own find a pic online that shows a similar break (there's bound to be one). Failing either of those two options you need to give a much more complete verbal description, "a broken 4x4 at the bottom" doesn't give prospective respondents nearly enough information. Same deal if you ask the Q again on the DIY site.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options for repairing your fence:

1. Get a $5 metal [T-post](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Actual-1-4-in-x-3-in-x-6-ft-Green-Steel-Farm-Fence-T-Post/4758566?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-LumberAndBuildingMaterials-_-WireFence-_-4758566:&CAWELAID=&kpid=4758566&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1887&k_clickID=go_625667893_34613739070_111132546670_aud-299487635210:pla-258795389990_c_9033589&gclid=CjwKCAiAs8XiBRAGEiwAFyQ-eugJ8yujYjpsAWNvyLV6j4Zyor-dz0Z2b8-YXHTWCHNXmQHeVIdvChoC8UYQAvD_BwE) or two and drive it in the ground near the broken 4x4. You may have to pound the T-post in at an angle to avoid hitting the concrete. Screw the 4x4 to the metal T-post. Easiest, cheapest, and fastest. This is a good temporary solution to a leaning fence.
2. Temporary brace the fence with 2x4's and detach the broken post from the fence. Using a drill and chisel, remove as much of the broken post from the concrete as possible. Get a new 4x4 post. Carefully measure the hole in the concrete. Use a handplane on the bottom of the new 4x4 post. Shave off about 1/2" from each of the sides so that it will fit in the hole you measured. There is no second chance, so make sure the post is smaller than the hole. Pound the new post into the hole in the cement. Use shims to level the post. Finally, reattach the fence.

Unless the 4x4 broke for a specific reason, like it was hit by a car, it's likely that rot caused the post to fail. If that's the case, it's likely that the other posts are rotten too. Check by stabbing with a screw driver. If the screw driver goes into the wood more then 1/2", it's rotten. Repairing a rotten fence (option #2) is almost certainly not worth it, as another post will likely fail in the near future. If the fence is rotten, it's best to prop it up (option #1) and then take care of it when the weather is more pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how much "good" post you have to work with above the concrete.

If you have enough to attach another post to what remains of the original post, you could cut off the original post and join a new one to the "stump" using a lap joint or scarf joint, then run a couple bolts through it to hold together.

You should probably orient the joint so that it provides maximum resistance to wind forces exerted against the fence. Posting a picture would be very helpful in this situation.

Comment: Broken just above concrete

Comment: This is a fine answer, so I edited to make it read a bit easier. Though, it is unclear if this question is actually on-topic. While we see if this is the case, there is no reason we can't encourage good answers.

Answer (score 0):

possibly drill one or more holes in the existing and the replacement then join them together with rebar and epoxy